# Android - using an image resource multiple times but changing alpha on only 1 instance

Tags: android, image, bitmap, alpha

I'm pretty sure I saw a specific command for this, but I can't remember what it's called, which means I can't Google it!

If I have an image resource, e.g. R.drawable.myimage , which gets used in a Linearview more than once and I want to change the alpha on just a single occurrence of that image, (normally, changing the alpha changes all the occurrences of that image), what command do I use to 'unlink' the changes of that image.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `Drawable.mutate()`.

Here is a code example that I've used. I think it is self-descriptive.

```
Drawable icon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actions_icon);

iconView.setImageDrawable(icon);        

if (action.isNew()) {
    icon.setAlpha(50);
}
else {
    icon.setAlpha(255);
}
```

You can also read an [article about Drawable mutations](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/drawable-mutations.html)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This will work also in this code...

```
Paint gpaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
gpaint.setAlpha(whatever number you want alpha);

canvas.drawBitmap(MainMenu.dressgirl, drx,dry,gpaint);
```

all others could be

```
canvas.drawBitmap(MainMenu.dressgirl, drx,dry,null);
```